# Hibernate multiple parameters setString generated Java

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I'm using hibernate, and trying to do a LIKE on certain fields.

I'm splitting a string, and then generating the HQL, with

```
table.entry LIKE :argsearch_0 OR table.entry LIKE :argsearch_0 OR 
table.entry LIKE :argsearch_1 OR table.entry LIKE :argsearch_1
```

(0 and 1 is in fact incremented with a counter).

But i get :

```
Not all named parameters have been set: [argsearch_0]
```

**First question :**

- Can I used 2 named parameter and do only 1 setParameter (or setString) :

  ```
  String nameParam = "argsearch_"+i;
  q.setParameter(nameParam, "%"+args[i]+"%");
  ```

**Second question :**

- Why my parameters are not working ?

Comment: Perhaps because your `i` is 1 at the beginning?

Comment: First question: yes. Second question: because you have a bug in your code.

Comment: I checked in debug, everything looks fine. the setString is done in an external function using the Query reference, could this be a problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Depends what you mean when you ask "Can I used 2 named parameter and do only 1 setParameter".

In your original query you have 2 named parameters ('argsearch_0' and 'argsearch_1') and each has 2 usages in the query.  So you have to call set for both 'argsearch_0' and 'argsearch_1'.  But you only call set once for each (actually you can call set multiple times for each parameter if you really want, but only the last once is used.

As for your second question, as someone already pointed out, its because you have a bug in your code.  You are not setting the value for the 'argsearch_0' parameter.

Comment: When i do "String nameParam = "argsearch_"+i;
q.setParameter(nameParam, "%"+args[i]+"%");" It should set the param ?

Comment: When I meant 2 parameters in the same query it would be something like : q = s.createQuery("select .... where ... :argsearch_0 LIKE ... OR :argsearch_0 ") and then only one q.setParameter("argsearch_0",..) ?

Comment: Correct.  That is really just one named parameter.  It just happens to have multiple occurrences in the query.  One call to set sets all of its occurrences

Answer (score 0):

```
  You can Try this  



    **Step 1--:** Add How many parameter you need just add in hashmap
   -------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    HashMap param_List=new HashMap();
    param_List.put("contactNo",22);

    
    **Step 2--:** Just You pass your Query
   -------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    Query query1 = session.createQuery("select * from emailTemplate  where c.contactNo =:contactNo");


  **Step 3--:** What ever Data type is no matters but get an output.
  -------------------------------------------------------------------

    for(Object paramKey : param_List.keySet())
    {
    query1.setParameter(paramkey.toString(), param_List.get(paramKey);
    }


 **Step 4--:**
-------------------------------------------------------------------
    String finalResult=query1.getSingleResult().toString();
```